# RegEx valid until it is not

Tags: regex

Let's say I want to match the following javascript

```
\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]{1,3}
```

as I'm entering things like

```
1asd23a

311eed123ss
```

So far so good; but I would rather not say valid or invalid after the whole string has been entered but rather as the string is being entered, I would like to return whether it could still potentially be valid.

Basically StartsWith but with any segment of the regex.

```
1asd23

311eed12
```

would still be valid because the entry could still be amended into the final form.
The beginning characters are not the ones that will make the regex invalid.

I hope I'm explaining this correctly.

Comment: So you want to bind the regex match to `keyup` of a text field?

Comment: Yeah, but I might have only a part of the string at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes the regex quite a bit uglier, but one option would be to make all of the later elements optional.  This needs to be done carefully to ensure that the later elements can only exist if all of the earlier ones do, so you will end up nesting several optional groups.  For example:

```
\d{1,3}([a-zA-Z]{1,3}(\d{1,3}([a-zA-Z]{1,3})?)?)?
```

Of course when the final string is entered you will want to validate it against your original regex.

Comment: Ahh, this is what I feared -- I had pretty much this very thing, I just thought perhaps something cleverer existed :-)